# call actions of controller but don't jump to the ERB view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, action

Thanks for your time!

I get routes in `routes.rb`:

```
get "loadreport/test"
post "loadreport/update"
```

The `test` function in `loadreport` controller is an empty function:

```
def test
end
```

The test.html.erb contains:

```
<form action="/loadreport/update?method=post" class="button_to" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    <textarea cols="30" id="post_body" name="comments" rows="5" maxlength=200>

    </textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

The `update` function will update database:

```
def update
  some_database.update(params[:comments])
end
```

Now when I click the `Update button` in `test.html.erb`, it will call `/loadreport/update` , and jump to `update.html.erb`. As `update.html.erb` doesn't exist, server will give me errors like : `Template is missing ... blah ...`

What I want to achieve is: when I click the `Update button` in `test.html.erb`, it will simply call `/loadreport/update`to update database, and then pop up a message box which says "update successful!", instead of jumping to another page.

How to change my code to achieve that? Can anyone give me some idea or some links on this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a Ajax post and get the return and show an alert. Try jQuery.

Or try:

```
def update
   some_database.update(params[:comments])
   redirect_to :test
end
```

This will redirect to the previous page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried Ajax and found it really powerful. I've done it with Ajax.